# react native orientation will not be work on above ios 16.0 version how to fix that

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

The code works just fine on Android devices and iOS versions up to 15. However, when it comes to iOS versions 16 and newer, it starts having problems. This means that if someone is using an iPhone or iPad with the latest iOS, the code might not work as expected. This can be a problem because you want your app to work smoothly for all users, regardless of their device or iOS version.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  BackHandler,
} from 'react-native';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation'

class InvoiceScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._hitAllInvoice()
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
      from:this.subtractDaysFromDate(new Date(), 10),
      to: new Date(),
      invoice_status: "-1",
      loading: false,
      flag: false,
    }

  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
    Orientation.lockToPortrait()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
    Orientation.lockToLandscape()

  }
  _renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginHorizontal: 5, marginTop: 5, borderBottomWidth:1,  borderBottomColor: '#a5a7a6', }}>
        <View style={[styles.shellStyle, { flex: 0.4, borderTopStartRadius: 10, backgroundColor: "white", }]}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'#'}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'DATE'}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'NAME'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'CONTACT'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={[styles.shellStyle,{flex:1.6}]}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'VIN NO.'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'INVOICE'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'AMOUNT'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.shellStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'STATUS'}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={[styles.shellStyle, { borderTopRightRadius: 10, backgroundColor: "white", }]}>
          <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{'ACTION'}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderFooter = () => {
    return <View style={{ height: 0.5, backgroundColor: 'black' }}></View>;
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: Colors.whiteText }]}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header
            containerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 16, paddingVertical: 5 }}
            status="Invoice Sheets"
            iconWidth={26}
            iconHeight={12}
            color={Colors.whiteText}
            isEditDelete={true}
            delete_icon={require('../assets/setting.png')}
            onPress={() => {
              if (this.state.flag == true) {
                this._hitAllInvoice()
                this.setState({
                  flag: false
                })
              }
              else {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('DashboardScreen')
              }
            }}
            // image={require('../assets/menuvertical.png')}
            onModal={() => {
              this.setState({ visible: true })
            }}
            backVisible={true}

          />
          <SearchInput
            onChangeText={(txt) => { this.props.searchInvoice(txt) }}
          />

          <SafeAreaView style={{ marginBottom: 5, flex: 1 }} >
            {this._renderHeader()}
            <FlatList
              data={this.props.invoice_list}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}

              // ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => "item" + index}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        {/* {this.state.loading ? (
          <View
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#000a',
              elevation: 10,
              position: 'absolute',
            }}>
            <MyLoading
              title="Please wait for a while..."
            />
          </View>
        ) : null} */}
      </View>

    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  shellStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    height: 35,
    elevation: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    margin: 1,
  },
  txtStyle: {
    fontFamily: Font.SourceSansPro,
    fontSize: 13,
    // height: 18,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#3D3D3D',
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  let s = state.indexReducer;
  let ss = state.indexJasReducer;

  return {
    invoice_list: ss.invoice_list,
    is_loading: s.is_loading,
    vendor_id: s.vendor_id,
    alert_msg: ss.alert_msg,
    search_invoice_list: ss.search_invoice_list,
    print_invoice: s.print_invoice_detail_list,



  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      hitInvoiceApi: (param) => hitInvoiceApi(param),
      setInvoiceList: (lists) => setInvoiceList(lists),
      resetInvoiceList: () => resetInvoiceList(),
      setAlertMSG: (msg) => setAlertMSG(msg),
      searchInvoice: (list) => searchInvoice(list),
      selectedInvoice: (contact) => selectedInvoice(contact),

      setAutoCustName: (param) => setAutoCustName(param),
      setEstimateCustId: (param) => setEstimateCustId(param),
      setInvoiceId: (invoice_id) => setInvoiceId(invoice_id),
      setAppointmentId: (appointment_id) => setAppointmentId(appointment_id),
      setEstimateCustVin_no: (param) => setEstimateCustVin_no(param),
      setPrintInvoiceDetails: (list) => setPrintInvoiceDetails(list),
      hitEmailInvoice: (param) => hitEmailInvoice(param),
      hitInvoiceEmail: (param) => hitInvoiceEmail(param)




    },
    dispatch,
  );
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceScreen);
```